# Bootstrap datepicker getDate and formating

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, range

I am using this datepicker as range:

http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/markup.html#date-range

1. I have trouble getting date output (when I click check dates) formatted in following styles like?

03/28/2018 or 03-28-2018

2. How could I display dates in input fields as for example?

Fri, Mar 16, 2018

```js
var dateRange = $('#datepicker-wrap').datepicker({

  container: '#datepicker-wrap'

})

var date_format = "MM/DD/YYYY",
    startDatePicker = $('#startDatePicker'),
    endDatePicker = $('#endDatePicker')

var a = moment().subtract(1, 'year').toDate(),
  b = moment().format(date_format);

startDatePicker.datepicker('setDate', a);
endDatePicker.datepicker('setDate', b);

$('#run').on('click', function() {

  console.log(startDatePicker.datepicker('getDate'), endDatePicker.datepicker('getDate'))

})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css
" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>




<div class="input-daterange" id="datepicker-wrap">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="startDate">START DATE</label>
    <div class='input-group'>
      <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" id="startDatePicker" required/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="endDate">END DATE</label>
    <div class='input-group'>
      <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" id="endDatePicker" required/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="run">get dates</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap-datepickers' `getDate` method returns a date object, as stated in their [documentation](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#getdate).
You have to format it yourself.

I recommend [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) for that. It's a great library for handling dates in JavaScript, which is quite a hassle when done manually (zero based months, cough...).

You might also want to check out [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38459153/how-to-change-the-date-format-in-bootstrap-datepicker).